# Google play-service resources error

Tags: android, google-play-services, eclipse-adt

I updated my SDK yesterday and after restarting eclipse all my projects which are using google services are broken. They only show me a red "!".

```
[2014-06-27 10:35:38 - BaseGameUtils] C:\Program Files\Android_ADT\sdk\extras\android\support

\v7\appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:24: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar'.
[2014-06-27 10:35:38 - BaseGameUtils] C:\Program Files\Android_ADT\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:28: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar'.
[2014-06-27 10:35:38 - BaseGameUtils] C:\Program Files\Android_ADT\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:32: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar.Solid'.
[2014-06-27 10:35:38 - BaseGameUtils] C:\Program Files\Android_ADT\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:36: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid'.
[2014-06-27 10:35:38 - BaseGameUtils] C:\Program Files\Android_ADT\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:40: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse'.
[2014-06-27 10:35:38 - BaseGameUtils] C:\Program Files\Android_ADT\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:122: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionButton'.
[2014-06-27 10:35:38 - BaseGameUtils] C:\Program Files\Android_ADT\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:125: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionButton'.
[2014-06-27 10:35:38 - BaseGameUtils] C:\Program Files\Android_ADT\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:129: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionButton.CloseMode'.
[2014-06-27 10:35:38 - BaseGameUtils] C:\Program Files\Android_ADT\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:133: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionButton.CloseMode'.
[2014-06-27 10:35:38 - BaseGameUtils] C:\Program Files\Android_ADT\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:137: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionButton.Overflow'.
[2014-06-27 10:35:38 - BaseGameUtils] C:\Program Files\Android_ADT\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:141: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionButton.Overflow'.
[2014-06-27 10:35:38 - BaseGameUtils] C:\Program Files\Android_ADT\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:44: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabBar'.
[2014-06-27 10:35:38 - BaseGameUtils] C:\Program Files\Android_ADT\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:48: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabBar'.
[2014-06-27 10:35:38 - BaseGameUtils] C:\Program Files\Android_ADT\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:52: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabBar.Inverse'.
[2014-06-27 10:35:38 - BaseGameUtils] C:\Program Files\Android_ADT\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:56: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabView'.
[2014-06-27 10:35:38 - BaseGameUtils] C:\Program Files\Android_ADT\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:60: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabView'.
[2014-06-27 10:35:38 - BaseGameUtils] C:\Program Files\Android_ADT\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:64: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabView.Inverse'.
[2014-06-27 10:35:38 - BaseGameUtils] C:\Program Files\Android_ADT\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:68: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabText'.
[2014-06-27 10:35:38 - BaseGameUtils] C:\Program Files\Android_ADT\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:72: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabText'.
[2014-06-27 10:35:38 - BaseGameUtils] C:\Program Files\Android_ADT\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:76: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabText.Inverse'.
[2014-06-27 10:35:38 - BaseGameUtils] C:\Program Files\Android_ADT\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:80: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionMode.Inverse'.
```

That is what console says to me. I don't know whats the problem. I setup a new workspace, linked libraries completely new to my projects and to BaseGameUtils, but the errors wouldn't be fixed. 
I even tried Eclipse Juno, Luna and ADT... It seems to be impossible to get my code working.

I really run out of ideas.

Comment: right click on one project..go to android and check the library part if there is any red mark library..

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply - the problem was made by my target versions and some library issues. So I voted your comment up. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the manifest there is a target version 13. Use it then below the Android manifest of a library.

In manifest file,

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="4"
    android:targetSdkVersion="13" />
```

Comment: Thanks, it was depending of the API-version(s) so your answer was right. But I solved it by clicking right on my project folder, going to "android" and at this menu I switched everything to API 19. After that I reloaded all libraries (again) and it worked. :) 
Great & Thanks!